# scipy / numpy linalg.eigval result interpretation

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am a newbie when it comes to using python libraries for numerical tasks. I was reading a paper on LexRank and wanted to know how to compute eigenvectors of a transition matrix. I used the `eigval` function and got a result that I have a hard time interpreting:

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(4,4))

a[0,0]=0.333
a[0,1]=0.333
a[0,2]=0
a[0,3]=0.333

a[1,0]=0.25
a[1,1]=0.25
a[1,2]=0.25
a[1,3]=0.25

a[2,0]=0.5
a[2,1]=0.0
a[2,2]=0.0
a[2,3]=0.5

a[3,0]=0.0
a[3,1]=0.333
a[3,2]=0.333
a[3,3]=0.333

print LA.eigval(a)
```

and the eigenvalue is:

```
[ 0.99943032+0.j         
-0.13278637+0.24189178j  
-0.13278637-0.24189178j  
  0.18214242+0.j        ]
```

Can anyone please explain what `j` is doing here? Isn't the eigenvalue supposed to be a scalar quantity? How can I interpret this result broadly?

Answer (score 2):

`j` is the imaginary number, the square root of minus one. In math it is often denoted by `i`, in engineering, and [in Python, it is denoted by `j`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24812444/190597).

Comment: thanks a lot .. now i know at least what else i should read up on before interpreting this result

Answer (score 1):

A *single* eigenvalue is a scalar quantity, but an *(m, m)* matrix will have *m* eigenvalues (and *m* eigenvectors). [The Wiki page on eigenvalues and eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Real_matrices) has some examples that might help you to get your head around the concepts.

As @unutbu mentions, `j` denotes the imaginary number in Python. In general, a matrix may have complex eigenvalues (i.e. with real and imaginary components) even if it contains only real values ([see here, for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67304)). Symmetric real-valued matrices are an exception, in that they are guaranteed to have only real eigenvalues.

Comment: thanks a ton ! the discussion you posted is beginning to make some sense now !