# What does the integer suffix J mean?

Tags: c++, c, integer, suffix

I have the following source:

```
int main() { 000J; }
```

With gcc 4.8.4 it compiles without errors.
I know there are suffixes like L or U, but I didn't find anything about J.

So what does it do?

Comment: Make sure you compile with `-std=c++11 -pedantic` to avoid compiler extensions. By default it will use `-std=gnu++11` (I think) which enables non-standard extensions.

Comment: You're right. With the `-pedantic` flag I get the same warning as zenith which points to the answer.

Comment: The C++ tag is misplaced here TBH. C++ only has [suffix `i`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) not `J`. It is another type, `std::complex<double>` instead of `_Complex`. And it's Standard C++, not an extension.

Comment: @MSalters gcc has `J` as an extension for C++ as well.

Comment: @zenith: True, the g++ tag would make sense.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I get a warning:

> Imaginary constants are a GNU extension

The `J` suffix is a GNU extension, which causes the literal to be of a `_Complex` type.

More info here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html

Comment: Hm, I didn't get that warning. Which version of gcc are you using and did you use any compile flags?

Comment: @happyMOOyear Try `-pedantic`.

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM 7.0 with `-pedantic`.

Comment: @Yakk as a mathematician, I take grave exception to this. WTH is a "Jamaginary Number"???

Comment: @imallett that's very similar to "WTH are Zintegers and Qationals???" (of course I know that's due to non-English origin, but still).

Comment: @Ruslan Q comes from "quotients", which makes sense. Z comes from German. Fortunately for my argument, "imaginary" in German is "imaginär", which still starts with `i` :)

Comment: @imallett j is standard notation for the y component of a vector, in this case it is the unit vector on the imaginary axis. i is used as the unit vector on real axis. So 1 + 1i (where i=sqrt 1) can be written as 1i + 1j (where i=unit). That's where it comes from.

Comment: @jcora That is literally the first credible argument I've heard for using `j`. Still, the standard basis is defined in R^n, as `i:=<1,0,0,0,0...>, j:=<0,1,0,0,0,...>, k:=<0,0,1,0,0,...>`. Abusing the notation for complex numbers is doing something _literally orthogonal_ to this correct meaning . . .

Comment: @imallett as someone from electronics background I should note that `j` is mainly used in electronics and electrical engineering to differentiate from `i` which is electric current

Comment: @jcora I don't think it's correct ["In electrical engineering and related fields, the imaginary unit is normally denoted by j to avoid confusion with electric current as a function of time, traditionally denoted by i(t) or just i. The Python programming language also uses j to mark the imaginary part of a complex number."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Alternative_notations). [Why are complex numbers in Python denoted with 'j' instead of 'i'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24812444/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That does seem like the more probable reason, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

As zenith mentioned, this is a GNU extension for writing imaginary literals. I really want to comment on the rationale of using `j` for this purpose as imallett is wondering but I don't have enough reputation to comment on zenith's answer. I'll leave this as an answer anyway as it might be helpful to others.

As [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html) explains, both `i` and `j` can be used to write imaginary literals using this GNU extension. The reason why `i` is used for this is obvious, but the reason why `j` is used as well is that `j` is commonly used to denote the imaginary unit in electrical engineering and control systems engineering to prevent confusion as `i` is already used to denote electrical current in those contexts.

Comment: This answer is even better, because the number becomes imaginary, not complex, the former being a subset of the latter.

Comment: `i` and `j` are also by convention often defined slightly differently such that `exp(-ix) = exp(jx)`.

Comment: @Forss Interesting - any reference for that claim?

Comment: @chux Found [this pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_007S11_sign.pdf) that explains the difference in convention.