# What does c++ constant value 1j mean?

Tags: c++

I am using Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31) to compile some code and I find that 1j could be a constant value.

In the following code snippet, I assign int b with value 1j and it compiles.

But j is not any variable I have defined.

Can anybody explain what is 1j? Or it is a compiler bug?

Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // What is 1j? Why this code can compile??
    int b = 1j;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen another post explaining this is complex number.

[What does the integer suffix J mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549444/what-does-the-integer-suffix-j-mean)

And using compiler option -pedantic would raise a warning for it.

Comment: so is it 1j or 2j?

Comment: It does not compile on my g++. The error message says "cannot convert complex int to int". So perhaps it stands for complex numbers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549444/what-does-the-integer-suffix-j-mean

Comment: It is 1j. I have modified it in the source code. And this is a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

The suffix `i` and `j` is used for complex numbers.