# Compiler does not give any error when using 'i' as an integer suffix

Tags: c, variables, debugging

I wrote this code by mistake.

I know it should be `2*i` instead of `2i`, naturally, but compiler does not give any error messages. What is the reason?

```
double getpi(int terms){
  int i;
  double answer = 0;
  for(i = 1; i <= terms; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 1){
      answer = answer + (4.0/(2i - 1));
    }else{
      answer = answer - (4.0/(2i - 1));
    } 
    
  }
  return answer;
}
```

I tried to check that values with debugger, but it confuses me more. The value of `answer` is 0.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549444/what-does-the-integer-suffix-j-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the integer suffix J mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33549444/what-does-the-integer-suffix-j-mean)

Answer (score 4):

Your `2i` is being interpreted as a [complex constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html).

The fact that this compiles tells me that you are using GCC. If you compile with more warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`), you'll get the warning that "imaginary constants are a GNU extension".

From [the GCC doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html):

> To write a constant with a complex data type, use the suffix ‘i’ or ‘j’ (either one; they are equivalent).