# A weird syntax in C/C++

Tags: c

[image: the question]
Translation:
"After running the code below, what is the value of k?'

This question was from my friend's homework(we were senior highs). He didn't know how to deal with this, so he asked me and then I tried to test this on my computer(`Debian 10, gcc-10.2.1`). The result is (A) , which means the value of k is 6. I reflected on the `if` statement but still had no idea. It utterly made no sense - especially the **syntax**(who will even write code in that way?) . That's why I would like to ask this question. Perhaps that's a bug I haven't met before.

The C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int i, j, k = 0;

    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; ++i ) {
        for ( j = 0 ; j <= 2 ; ++j ) {
            
            if ( i != 1i != 2 && j != 1 ) {
                k = k + j;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", k);
        
    return 0;
}
```

Why can the following `if` statement work?

```
if ( i != 1i != 2 && j != 1 )
```

And what's the value of `1i`?

Comment: And please [do not upload images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875) when asking a question.

Comment: I reckon you are surprised that `1i` isn't rejected?

Comment: @chris It is a [GNU extension for writing imaginary literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617143/12002570). See duplicate: [What does the integer suffix J mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617143/12002570)

Comment: @chris I think the homework is about operator precedence; e.g. whether the expression is `(i != 1i) != 2` or `i != (1i != 2)`

Comment: What is the value of ```1i``` ?

Comment: @wuj-jay I've added more dupes in the dupe list. For examole, [Why can't we do three-way comparison in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526264/why-cant-we-do-three-way-comparison-in-c) and [Comparing a variable to a range of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830644/comparing-a-variable-to-a-range-of-values).

Comment: @wuj-jay That's what [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617143/12002570) explains. It is a [GNU extension for writing imaginary literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617143/12002570). Kindly read the duplicates.

Comment: @wuj-jay 1 as an imaginary number, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number

Comment: @wuj-jay Alas, since the question was _closed_, there is no very good way to explain everything wrong with the exam’s question. The `1i`’s value is not really relevant except to say it is a non-integer not equal to `i`, producing a boolean value of `true`. (Which is _then_ used in the next `!=` part of the expression.)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot, I should have taken a closer look at the choices before defaulting to `&&`, but `||` would still produce 8 and be a pretty normal precedence question compared to a GNU extension for complex numbers that you'd have no reason to teach in a senior high class.

Comment: Multiple choice is missing "Code isn't run, because it is rejected in review"

Comment: I have to admit, this is the first time in many, many moons that I have really enjoyed a horrid test question.

Comment: Really appreciate it to you guys who answered my dumb question. I didn't know it's about the compiler extension.