# Variable dimensionality of a meshgrid with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I try to create a meshgrid with n dimensions.
Is there a nicer way to call meshgrid with n column vectors than with the if clause I am using?

Edit: The goal is to use it for user-defined n (2-100) without writing 100 if clauses.

The second line in the if clauses reduces the grid so column(n) < column(n+1)

Example:

```
import numpy as np
dimension = 2
range = np.arange(0.2,2.4,0.1)
if dimension == 2:
    grid = np.array(np.meshgrid(range,range)).T.reshape(-1,dimension)
    grid = np.array(grid[[i for i in range(grid.shape[0]) if grid[i,0]<grid[i,1]]])
 elif dimension == 3:
     grid = np.array(np.meshgrid(range,range,range)).T.reshape(-1,dimension)
     grid = np.array(grid[[i for i in range(grid.shape[0]) if grid[i,0]<grid[i,1]]])
     grid = np.array(grid[[i for i in range(grid.shape[0]) if grid[i,1]<grid[i,2]]])
```

Edit: The solution was posted below:

```
dimension = 2
r = np.arange(0.2,2.4,0.1)
grid=np.array(np.meshgrid(*[r]*n)).T.reshape(-1,n)

for i in range(0,n-1):
    grid = np.array([g for g in grid if g[i]<g[i+1]])
```

Comment: Are you just bothered by the `meshgrid(range, range)` v `meshgrid(range,range,range)`?  I don't see, off hand, what the rest of your code does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a multi-dimensional version of arange/linspace in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208359/is-there-a-multi-dimensional-version-of-arange-linspace-in-numpy)

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to overwrite native python routines, especially one as useful as `range`.

Comment: He's already generating the mult-dimensional grid with `meshgrid`.  The 'duplicate' adds nothing that he isn't already doing.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes, as it is one of the things I could not easily scale. After your comment I looked up numpy.repeat, which seems to be what I want for n-repeats or I just use your *[r]*n suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisMueller: Thanks for the tip! (I just copied a MWE and renamed my variables to make it clear what I am trying to do without thinking too much about it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't fully absorbed your approach and goals, but here's a partial simplification

```
In [399]: r=np.arange(3)           # simpler range for example
In [400]: grid=np.meshgrid(*[r]*2)   # use `[r]*3` for 3d case
In [401]: grid=np.array(grid).T.reshape(-1,2)
In [402]: np.array([g for g in grid if g[0]<g[1]])  # simpler comprehensions
Out[402]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

`itertools.product` makes that 2 column grid easier:

```
In [403]: from itertools import product
In [404]: np.array([g for g in product(r,r) if g[0]<g[1]])
Out[404]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

That is, your `grid` before filtering is

```
In [407]: grid
Out[407]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

and `product` is

```
In [406]: list(product(r,r))
Out[406]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

`product` has a `repeat` parameter that makes this even easier:

```
In [411]: list(product(r,repeat=2))
Out[411]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

You still need the `if` clause to apply the 2 step filtering for dim=3.  I guess the could written iteratively

```
for i in range(0,dimension-1):
   grid = [g for g in grid if g[i]<g[i+1]]
```