# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. numpy error

Tags: python, numpy

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I get the above error for this code. I did not get this kind of error a couple of months ago. But I am getting it now. How can I solve this?

```py
t = np.linspace(np.zeros((2, 2)), np.ones((2, 2)), 20)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-187bbe847597> in <module>
----> 1 t = np.linspace(np.zeros((2, 2)), np.ones((2, 2)), 20)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype)
    122     if num > 1:
    123         step = delta / div
--> 124         if step == 0:
    125             # Special handling for denormal numbers, gh-5437
    126             y /= div

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you show the full error trace?

Comment: What version of `numpy` are you using?  try `np.version.version`.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I execute your code example on my machine (python 3.7.3 and numpy 1.16.4). Which versions of python and numpy are you using?

Comment: I can replicate this error in `numpy` versions before 1.16.  That code in the error trace does not exist after then.  Previous to that nd inputs to `linspace` were not supported.

Comment: I am using '1.14.5'

Comment: Were you previously using a higher version?  That code only works in version 1.16 and higher.

Comment: I doubt it.. I have not done anything other than running some codes on my anaconda. I am trying updating numpy now.

Comment: Have you installed any packages that might require a previous version of `numpy`?

Comment: I have tried (conda update conda & conda update numpy) and it shows that I am using Python 3.7.1 and numpy 1.15.4. But I still get the same error message.

Comment: I am not entirely sure at this point. But I am pretty confident that I only use numpy, pandas and matplotlib 99% of the time... so that is unlikely the case.

Comment: At this point your question is about how to update `numpy` past 1.16.  If it's less than that, the code won't work.  Maybe try another question?

Comment: True... I can't seem to update `numpy` higher than 1.15.4. I will ask another question. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate this error in `numpy` versions before 1.16.  Previous to that, `np.linspace` did not accept `ndarray` inputs for `stop` and `start`.

@JHY confirmed current version is 1.14.5.  Try updating `numpy`

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply because `np.zeros((2,2))` and `np.ones((2,2))` create arrays with 4 values and you are trying to create an array with `20` samples.

`t = np.linspace(np.zeros((2, 2)), np.ones((2, 2)), 1)`

Creates no problem ,simply because the length of the array.

Result:

`array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])`

Comment: All you've done is short-circuit the error message by making `step = NaN`.  There is no case where you'd actually want `np.linspace(x, y, 1)`.  The error message is from using a functionality of `linspace` that didn't exist before `numpy` 1.16 in a previous version.

Comment: I do need it to work with numbers greater than 1. And it used to work before I don't know why it doesn't now

Answer (score 0):

Update your numpy.

**for python 2**

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --user
```

*tables needed to update too*

```
pip install tables --upgrade
```

**for python 3**

```
pip3 install numpy --upgrade --user
```

*similarly, for python 3*

```
pip3 install tables --upgrade
```

For complete working of numpy after updating them you would need to update tables to.
After that run your code, the error will be removed.