# generating a set of equally spaced points in 3d

Tags: python, math, 3d, space, points

I have an object  which is a point with 3d cordinates:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

and a cuboid of the following dimensions

```
LD1 = 0.05
LD2 = 0.025
Ld3 = 0.025
```

how can I generate a list of lets say 81-100 equally spaced points within this cuboid(!!!I don want any of them on the surface)?
NOTE: these points I am going to use to generate a set of points on a sphere around each one

I tried generating a mesh and removing the part on the surface as seen below:

```
if xyz[i][0] != 0 and xyz[i][0] != LD1 and xyz[i][1] != 0 and xyz[i][1] !=LD23 and xyz[i][2]!=0 and xyz[i][2] !=LD23:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a multi-dimensional version of arange/linspace in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208359/is-there-a-multi-dimensional-version-of-arange-linspace-in-numpy)

Comment: I tried  but it didn't  work

Comment: You tried what? What didn't work? What do you mean "it didn't work"? Was the distribution of the points not what you expect? Was there an error message?

Comment: what happened is that I got a grid, what I want is like a set of internal points spaced equally.

Comment: its like selecting the internal points of the grid and removing the ones on the surface ,but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Weeeeeell if the only issue is that you don't want the points on the surface, you could try giving slightly smaller dimensions to the function.

Comment: I tried another idea, you can see the edit in the post, it still needs improvement.

Comment: well both your solution and mine with the conditioning worked ,so thanks a lot.