# Python - Interpolating a grid in given border

Tags: python, grid, 2d, interpolation, cubic-spline

For a project I want a grid like this: 5x5. The points should be movable later but I got that i guess.

[image: standard grid]

What i wanna be able to do now is to interpolate for example 100x50 points in this grid of 5x5 marker points but not just linear, CUBIC in both axis. I cant wrap my head around it. I saw how to lay scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline through for example the 5 horizontal markers at the top but how do i combine it with the vertical warp?

is there a fnc to interpolate a grid in a given frame like this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html):

> Interpolate over a 2-D grid.
> x, y and z are arrays of values used to approximate some function f: z = f(x, y) which returns a scalar value z. This class returns a function whose call method uses spline interpolation to find the value of new points.

So you have an array `orig` that you want to generate 100x50 array `res` using bicubic interpolation

```
# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126099/17595968
from scipy import interpolate as interp
import numpy as np

orig = np.random.randint(0, 100, 25).reshape((5, 5))

W, H = orig.shape
new_W, new_H = (100, 50)
map_range = lambda x: np.linspace(0, 1, x)

f = interp.interp2d(map_range(W), map_range(H), orig, kind="cubic")
res = f(range(new_W), range(new_H))
```

Edit:

If what you want is coordinates of 100x50 grid in 5x5 grid you can use `numpy.meshgrid`:

```
#From https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208788/17595968
import numpy as np

W, H = 5, 5
new_W, new_H = 100, 50

x_step = W / new_W
y_step = H / new_H
xy = np.mgrid[0:H:y_step, 0:W:x_step].reshape(2, -1).T
xy = xy.reshape(new_H, new_W, 2)
xy
```

Comment: What is arr in your example? is it orig or res?

Comment: Also i dont wanna interpolate values to be clear, i just need to know, if i interpolated between the 5x5 points where the 100x50 points would be distributed to

Comment: Fixed code. So you want to have a 2D array of where the 100x50 points will map to on the original grid? If not please provide sample input and output I'm having a hard time getting what you want