# Python: unpacking string of integers to complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a faster way of reading a buffer of integers to an array of complex numbers?

This works good (if buffer is with floats):

```
import numpy, struct
binary_string = struct.pack('2f', 1,2)
print numpy.frombuffer(binary_string, dtype=numpy.complex64)
# [ 1. + 2.j]
```

But, if readed buffer is with integers, there is a problem:

```
import numpy, struct
binary_string = struct.pack('2i', 1,2)
print numpy.frombuffer(binary_string, dtype=numpy.complex64)
# [  1.40129846e-45 +2.80259693e-45j]
```

So, I can't find any faster way to convert it except with a slicing:

```
import numpy, struct
#for int32
binary_string = struct.pack('2i', 1,2)
ints = numpy.frombuffer(binary_string, dtype=numpy.int32)
print ints[::2] + 1j*ints[1::2]
# [ 1. + 2.j]

#for int16
binary_string = struct.pack('2H', 1,2)
ints = numpy.frombuffer(binary_string, dtype=numpy.int16)
print ints[::2] + 1j*ints[1::2]
# [ 1. + 2.j]
```

Also, is there any of a "complex number with integers" datatype, so a result could look like:

```
[1 + 2j]
```

Thanks.

Comment: About the part about complex numbers, you can check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-usage-in-python)

Comment: "faster" is almost never the right goal.

Comment: ok about "faster", but is there some "native" numpy method except slicing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a string packed with 4-byte ints you could use:

```
In [35]: np.frombuffer(struct.pack('2i', 1,2), dtype='i4').astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)
Out[35]: array([ 1.+2.j], dtype=complex64)
```

For a string packed with 2-byte ints you could use:

```
In [34]: np.frombuffer(struct.pack('2H', 1,2), dtype='i2').astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)
Out[34]: array([ 1.+2.j], dtype=complex64)
```

The idea here is to let `np.frombuffer` read the string using an integer dtype appropriate for the string. Then use `astype` to preserve the integer *values* but change the underlying representation to `float32`s. Then use `view` to reinterpret the underlying data as `complex64`s (so every two `float32`s get regarded as one `complex64`).

Comment: That's really make my script to works faster (for about 40%), and it is a native method other than slicing. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks.