# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' (already used int(str))

Tags: python, string, complex-numbers

I am writing a function that calculates complex number multiplication using python2.7. The funtion is:

```
def complexNumberMultiply(self, a, b):
    """
    :type a: str
    :type b: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    c,d = a.split('+')
    e,f = b.split('+')
    d = int(d[:-1])
    f = int(f[:-1])

    print c,d,e,f
    return '%s+%si' % (c * e - d * f, c * f + d * e)
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> In complexNumberMultiply
>       return '%s+%si' % (c * e - d * f, c * f + d * e)
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

My questions is, why my int(d[:-1]) didn't turn the string (e.g. -2) into an integer?

Comment: 1) provide the input you use to test this function 2) you don't convert `c` and `e` 3) are you aware that there is a complex number type in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You converted `d` and `f` to `int`, but what about `c` and `e`? You are trying to do `c * e` and you can't multiply a string by a string.

Consider:

```
def complexNumberMultiply(a, b):
    """
    :type a: str
    :type b: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    split_a = a.split('+')
    split_b = b.split('+')
    c, d = int(split_a[0]), int(split_a[-1][0])
    e, f = int(split_b[0]), int(split_b[-1][0])

    print (c,d,e,f)
    return '%s + %si' % (c * e - d * f, c * f + d * e)

print(complexNumberMultiply('1+2i', '3+4i'))
# 1 2 3 4
# -5+10i
```

Or use `complex` which is a builtin type in Python:

```
>>> complex('1+2j') * complex('3+4j')
(-5+10j)
>>> (1+2j) * (3+4j)
(-5+10j)
```

Comment: Thanks. How come I didn't even notice c,e > <|||

Comment: `(1+2j)*(3+4j)` also works - no need to invoke the `complex()` constructor.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: of course, but the input is what it is…

Answer (score 2):

Imaginary numbers are recognized in Python as objects, just like integers, floats...:

```
>>> complexN = 33 + 2j
>>> complexN 
(33+2j)
>>> complexN.real          # real part
33.0
>>> complexN.imag          # imaginary part
2.0
```

Addition of complex numbers:

```
>>> complex + (33+2j)
(66+4j)
```

the `2j` is the imaginary part and the real part being 33. This is the recommended way to deal with complex numbers in Python.

But if you insist on using your function for experimenting, I don't think using `str` and then converting to `int` is a good way. Why not just use numbers straightforward? This way you'll avoid the bells and whistles of formatting the inputs to your function.

Also see: 
[Complex numbers usage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-usage-in-python)