# Convert complex FFT array for getting amplitude

Tags: python, fft

How do I do this, I have complex values at each array index composed of a real part and an imaginary part, how to get a distinct workable value out of these.
I want to get the amplitude for each sample, the formula somewhere I read was `sqrt(x^2+y^2); x[i], y[i]` (for each 'i'th index of FFT array, come from a C background, newbie to Python).

```
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np

rate, data = wav.read('file.wav')

fft_out = fft(data)
print(fft_out)
```

The above code gives me complex no array, how do I get the required output?
PS
Trying to make a Speech to Text converter (Initial step, extract useful info out of a sample file).

Comment: You can just `abs` to get the magnitude of complex values, i.e. `abs(fft_out)` in your example.

Comment: Can you please tell me, what is happening here?

Comment: See documentation for `abs`, and maybe read some related SO answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370696/253056).

Comment: ok, thanks, searched for it, got it.