# Return a complex number from function

Tags: python

I want to assign an imaginary number to a variable:

```
import math

a = sqrt(4)j
print(a)
```

This results in a SyntaxError:

```
Line 3: SyntaxError: bad input ('j')
```

I can assign an imaginary number to variable like this:

```
a = 2j
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: (closed) dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-usage-in-python

Comment: @Aran-Fey That question was closed, though I found the answers useful. I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use [`complex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) to return:

> `real + imag*1j` or convert a string or number to a complex number

```
>>> a = complex(0,math.sqrt(4))
>>> a
2j
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) function.

```
>>> complex(0, sqrt(4))
2j
```