# How does abs function work with this code : abs(3 + 4j)?

Tags: python, function

I already know how does abs function works.***I mean it only shows you how far the number is from zero***

The only thing i can't just get is with this example:

```
print(abs(3 + 4j)) # prints 5 !! Why ?
```

Comment: `3 + 4j` is a complex number, and its absolute value is `sqrt(3 ** 2 + 4 ** 2) = 5`, so what is surprising here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complex numbers usage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-usage-in-python)

Comment: This is more of a maths question than a programming question.

Comment: [Absolute value of a complex number](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/absolute-value-complex-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the rest of the answers stated above, `3+4j` is a complex number and the formula of calculating the absolute value of a complex number `x+yi` is `sqrt( (x^2) + (y^2) )`. In your case it's:

```
 sqrt(3^2 + 4^2) = sqrt(9 + 16) = sqrt(25) = 5
```

Comment: I got it @Vasilis G. , as my first language is not english i did not know how do they calculate the absolute value of a complex number, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because for complex numbers abs(number) will return magnitude of Complex Numbers.

Magnitude value will counted as :
√x2+y2 = √(3² + 4²) = √(9 + 16) = √(25) = 5.0

So abs with complex number will return magnitude of complex numbers.

for further reference you can use https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abs-in-python/.

Answer (score 1):

Because in python, `3+4j` is complex number and python calculates the absolute value or magnitude of the complex number when you do `abs()` on it. Magnitude of `3+4j` is `5`. Try this :

```
type(3+4j)
```

It should give `<class 'complex'>`.

**Note** : Magnitude of a complex number `a+bj` is `((a**2+b**2)**0.5)`