# How to get original sound after FFT?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I am applying a FFT to my sound like this:

```
from scipy.fft import fft

samplerate, data = wavfile.read('./sound.wav')
fft_sound = fft(data)
```

Is there a reversal method which I can use to go from `fft_sound` back to `data`?

Here's what I did:

```
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('./StarWars3.wav')

print(data)
print(ifft(fft(data)))
```

But the outcome looks completely different:

```
[    0     0     0 ... -1502    26   414]
[ 0.00000000e+00-1.17911210e-13j -6.75789623e-13-4.22368515e-14j
  0.00000000e+00+7.03947524e-14j ... -1.50200000e+03-5.15824216e-14j
  2.60000000e+01+3.23030463e-13j  4.14000000e+02+9.36792340e-13j]
```

Did I use it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reversal method which I can use to go from `fft_sound` back to `data`?

Yes, it's called *inverse discrete Fourier transform*.

Just like the `fft` function, SciPy has a function for it; unsurprisingly named [`ifft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.ifft.html).

> Did I use it correctly?

It returns a complex-valued array, where the `j` suffix denotes the imaginary part (see [Complex numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-in-python) and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

As its documentation says,

> [...] `ifft(fft(x)) == x` to within numerical accuracy.

The outcome is shown in scientific notation, so it looks different but numerically it is very close:

- `-1502` became `-1.50200000e+03-5.15824216e-14j` (real part is `-1.50200000e+03`, which is -1502; imaginary part is `-5.15824216e-14`, which is very close to 0)
- `26` became `2.60000000e+01+3.23030463e-13j` (real part is `2.60000000e+01`, which is 26; imaginary part is `3.23030463e-13`, which is very close to 0)

etc.

Comment: So is removing the imaginary part the correct implementation? Is there a reference?

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent to rounding to the nearest real number. I don't have a reference.

Comment: It is quite interesting for data visualization, we do abs(complex value) after fft and (complex value).real after ifft