# Python complex type

Tags: python

I found myself being really rigorous about specifications of everything. So this one thing came too much confusing. I can't find any proof of built-in **complex** type being subclass of **numbers.Complex**. This problem doesn't apply to other numeric types like int or float as they're given those confirmations.

Generally speaking, what should I do if I face deficiences like this one. I think it's expectable to meet them because of this document's quite narrative style.
https://docs.python.org/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Why not just check with `issubclass(complex, numbers.Complex) -> True`?

Comment: @TeerapadPipadboonyarat Does it? I don't see the answer in that link.

Comment: Is your question "is built-in complex a subclass of numbers.Complex" or "what should I do if I face deficiencies"?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f8b9a3506fefeba01a18eda0e06c037393be4bf/Lib/numbers.py#L144) should help?