# Making the complex(a, b) command work with functions from the math module

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I have been building math tools in Python without numpy and am wondering if I have to use numpy to do more than add and subtract using the complex numbers built into Python.

I've tried just plugging the complex command into my functions, for example:

```
import math

def f(a, b):
    return math.cos(complex(a, b))

print(f(1, 1))
```

and it won't calculate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370637/complex-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#module-cmath) module provides complex number variants of the math module functions:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> z = 3 + 4j
>>> cmath.sqrt(z)
(2+1j)
>>> cmath.cos(z) (-27.034945603074224-3.8511533348117775j)
```